# UI-grid exporter: How to right align data within the table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, angular-ui-grid, jspdf

I want to right align certain elements of the exported ui grid pdf.
I have a header, main table, and footer that i have exported.  I would like only the parts of the table and footer that contain numbered data to be right aligned.

This code aligns the text to the center.  It is the column header for the table.

```
exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: {fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red', alignment: 'center'},
```

This does not solve the issue because it right aligns ALL the content that is exported. That's not what I want.

```
exporterPdfDefaultStyle: {fontSize: 9, alignment: 'right'},
```

The header (which is its own table), table data, and footer are all left aligned by default.

Any exporters that can help me right alignment certain parts of my table?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within my columnDefs, I use

```
exporterPdfAlign: 'right',
```

this aligns the content under each column header